# How to protect/hide your userId and web token in react?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm developing simple CRUD app in react and express. Now, When user SignIn, I store the userId(from database) and JWT(web token) in localstorage and I use this userId and token to check `isSignin()` and `isAuthenticated()` for future API calls. Now, If I deploy or make production build of this application, the user info will be clearly visible in my localstorage and it can be threat to my security. Can anyone please tell me how to hide this information and implement these mathods in production ready app? I want deploy it on AWS. Because, I've seen on so many website, we cannot see our own userId other credentials in our own localstorage.

here my methods. The req are coming from front end in react and as soon as I am getting response to front-end my react code is storing that in localstorage.

```
exports.isSignedIn = expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  userProperty: "auth"
});



exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  let checker = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;
  if (!checker) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: "ACCESS DENIED"
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Randall Degges](https://dev.to/rdegges) gave a very detailed explanation about why you shouldn't use localstorage to store sensitive data. I will point out the main part.

> If you need to store sensitive data, you should always use a
>   server-side session. Sensitive data includes:
>
> User IDs, Session IDs, JWTs, Personal information, Credit card information,
>   API keys, And anything else you wouldn't want to publicly share on
>   Facebook If you need to store sensitive data, here's how to do it:
>
> 1. When a user logs into your website, create a session identifier for
>      them and store it in a cryptographically signed cookie. If you're
>      using a web framework, look up “how to create a user session using
>      cookies” and follow that guide.
> 2. Make sure that whatever cookie library your web framework uses is
>      setting the httpOnly cookie flag. This flag makes it impossible for a
>      browser to read any cookies, which is required in order to safely use
>      server-side sessions with cookies. Read Jeff Atwood's article for more
>      information. He's the man.
> 3. Make sure that your cookie library also sets the SameSite=strict
>      cookie flag (to prevent CSRF attacks), as well as the secure=true flag
>      (to ensure cookies can only be set over an encrypted connection).
> 4. Each time a user makes a request to your site, use their session ID
>      (extracted from the cookie they send to you) to retrieve their account
>      details from either a database or a cache (depending on how large your
>      website is)
> 5. Once you have the user's account info pulled up and verified, feel
>      free to pull any associated sensitive data along with it
>      This pattern is simple, straightforward, and most importantly: secure.
>      And yes, you can most definitely scale up a large website using this
>      pattern. Don't tell me that JWTs are “stateless” and “fast” and you
>      have to use local storage to store them: you're wrong!

Source/Read more: [Please Stop Using Local Storage](https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04)

Comment: that was quite elaborate. Thanks a lot @rotimi-best . will get back to you soon.